# Can we use .fit_transform() directly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scale

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler()
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
```

can I directly do:

```
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(mymatrix)
```

without doing `scaler.fit(mymatrix)` first?

If not, why so? What is the difference? Doesnt `scaler.fit_transform()` function already compute the variance and mean values too before transforming?

Comment: Surely you can.

Comment: Yes you can directly perform this method. fit_transform() method internally perform fit() and then transform the data. So, if you apply fit() and then transform() or fit_transform directly. It is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the docs  [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) you can, because `fit_transform` performs first a `fit(),` after that it applies a `transform()`.